# Are my answers to this question about 不仅 appropriate, and how can I make them more elaborate?

Tags: word-choice, usage

This is an exercise in the book 标准教程HSK4上 about using [不仅](http://dict.cn/%E4%B8%8D%E4%BB%85) (bùjǐn; "not only") together with [也](http://dict.cn/%E4%B9%9F), [还](http://dict.cn/%E8%BF%98), or [而且](http://dict.cn/%E8%80%8C%E4%B8%94).

> [image: Exercise in 标准教程HSK4上]

I transcribe it below:

> 练一练 Practice
> 完成句子 Complete the sentences.
> (1) 李老师不仅喜欢看电影，＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿．（也）
> (2) 他＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿，还喜欢游泳．（不仅）
> (3) 不仅我会做中国菜，＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿．（而且）

I came out with these answers:

> 李老师不仅喜欢看电影，**他也喜欢看电视**．
> Teacher Li not only likes to watch movies, he also likes to watch TV.
>
> 他**不仅会走路**，还喜欢游泳．
> He not only can walk, he likes to swim.
>
> 不仅我会做中国菜，**而且我也会吃中国菜**．
> Not only can I cook Chinese food, I can also *eat* Chinese food.

I'm not certain these are even suitable answers, and they don't seem particularly elaborate or interesting.

**Question**: Are my answers to this question about 不仅 appropriate, and how can I make them more elaborate?

My reflections on my answers:

The first is unexciting; it seems 李老师 is the most boring person in the world.  Possibly ...他也以前是电影中的表演 is more interesting (...he used to act in movies), but it's a bit out-of-character for 李老师, and it seems strange to begin the sentence pointing out how he likes to watch movies if we're subsequently going to say he acts in them.

For the second, I'm envisaging a toddler who is just starting to walk, and their (proud) parent talking about their child's abilities.  I'm unsure about this, but couldn't come up with a satisfying answer.

The third is meant to be a joke; the grammar indicates the sentence would continue with something more exciting, but instead it's unexpectedly mundane.  I was also thinking of something along the lines of ...而且我也会做西餐, but there seems to be a mismatch between 中国菜 and 西餐 (and I'm not sure if [西菜](http://dict.cn/%E8%A5%BF%E8%8F%9C) is actually a thing).

Comment: alternative for 2: skate: 溜冰，滑冰（就是从事另外休闲运动)

Comment: re answer： 与溜冰鞋相比，滑雪设备 -- 滑雪板 、 滑雪杆和滑雪靴非常贵。当然为了去溜冰也需要个溜冰场、结冰的湖面或水道所以练习滑旱冰怎么样？

Comment: Grammatically correct, but semantically strange, nobody say things like that, you can strip Chinese and only looking at the English version, it's still strange. Doesn't seem to be Chinese problem.西菜 is not a word.

Comment: Considering the key point of this practice is 不仅, I think your answer is just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pay attention to the word **after** 不仅, 还, and etc. Typically, the things after those words are the emphasis point.

So:

- The first one 李老师不仅 **喜欢** 看电影, 也**喜欢** xxx. xxx could be something
  he likes, such as 玩游戏，看电视，踢足球, ... E.g. 李老师不仅喜欢看电影, 也喜欢踢足球.
- The second one 还 **喜欢** 游泳 indicates that 他不仅**喜欢** xxx has been
  said. And again xxx could be something he likes, such as 玩游戏，看电视，踢足球,
  ... E.g. 他不仅喜欢玩游戏, 还喜欢游泳
- The third one 不仅 **我** 会做中国菜 suggests that the later part should be
  而且xxx也会（做中国菜）. xxx can be any person. E.g. 不仅我会做中国菜, 而且他们也会（做中国菜）.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

> 李老师不仅喜欢看电影，**他也喜欢看话剧。/ 他也喜欢演电影。**
>   It's OK. 李老师 could be an acting teacher.
>
> 他**不仅喜欢滑雪**，还喜欢游泳。
>   The two sports are at the same level would be better.
>
> 不仅我会做中国菜，**而且我朋友也会。**
>   Here, if 我 is after 不仅，then we can chose another subject as counterpart.